# iOS Auto layout, alignment in columns

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, autolayout

I want to build header with titles and cells with labels for tableView, the  header will be contained from 4 items, like name, email, date, sex. I will made it for iPad.

My purpose is to have this labels in 4 alignment columns. But in my implementation if first label have long text it will shift other labels. Also the second can do the same thing.

This tableView should resizes for landscape and portrait iPad. I do it in IB.

How can I set maximum size for one label?

How can I set X position to second label if first label can have different size(base on it's content)?

Answer (score 0):

To set the maximum size select the width constraint. then, in the size inspector at right pane. change the relation to less that or equal.

To adjust the 2nd label based on the 2nd one. add a leading constraint between the 2nd label and the 1st label.

Comment: 1. Thanks, for you response, but I am not sure that I need to have fixed size in points here. maybe i need to use percentage?  2. But will the 2nd labels will be alignment for every cell in tableView in that case? 1st column can have different sizes